# How the handshaking between gigya,my app and my server takes place?

Tags: ios, gigya

I want to use social login feature of Gigya SDk in my iOS app.
But when user logs in using Gigya SDK from my mobile application,how come my server will get notified about this event?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I wanted to get the bigger picture of handshaking when we use Gigya SDK.I dont want details in particular case but i wish to get the overview of Social login process w.r.t. any other server.
There was no need to down vote the question else you could have provided the answer in short.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really to broad to answer.  The Gigya SDKs are just a layer that sits atop the Gigya REST API.  It's a simple request/response scheme that you use as a service that is consumed.  If you need Gigya data sent to another 3rd party source, then you must facilitate that with your own code.   The mobile SDK and Gigya API in general doesn't push data to 3rd party sources.